# node and mongo:retrieval of documents using array of ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

i have two collections.
1)notifications
2)forums

the schemas for these collections are present in seperate js files notifications.js and forum.js as the following

### notifications.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(

{

    username: String,
    message: String,
    date: Date,
    deleted: String,
    commentids: [{id:String}]

});module.exports = mongoose.model('notifications', notificationSchema);
```

### forum.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(

{

    username: String,
    message: String,
    date: Date,
    deleted: String,
    commentids: [{id:String}]

});    module.exports = mongoose.model('notifications', notificationSchema);
```

forums collection looks like this:

```
  {  "_id" : ObjectId("5751e2b315cdbc58164df7cd"),
    "notificationids" : [
            ObjectId("5751e2be15cdbc58164df7d0"),
            ObjectId("5751e2c415cdbc58164df7d1")
    ],
    "__v" : 0
  }
```

notificationids is an array in forums collection which stores the ids of corresponding notifications.

and notifications collection looks as shown below

```
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5751e2be15cdbc58164df7d0"),
    "username" : "ab",
    "message" : "hello",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-06-03T20:04:14.487Z"),
    "deleted" : "false",
    "commentids" : [ ],
    "__v" : 0
    }
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5751e2c415cdbc58164df7d1"),
    "username" : "ab",
    "message" : "how are you",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-06-03T20:04:20.769Z"),
    "deleted" : "false",
    "commentids" : [ ],
    "__v" : 0
    }
```

*now i have to write a query in mongoose to select all the "notifications" documents whose "_id"s are present in the notificationids array of forums collection.
i.e, since here notificationids=[     ObjectId("5751e2be15cdbc58164df7d0"),
                                      ObjectId("5751e2c415cdbc58164df7d1")],
the query must return all the documents of notifications collection as ids 
5751e2be15cdbc58164df7d0 and 5751e2c415cdbc58164df7d1 are present in notifications collection*

i have written a file server.js  like this in nodejs..

### server.js

```
var ForumModel = require('../models/forum');
var NotificationModel=require('../models/notifications');
var mongoose=require("mongoose");
ForumModel.find({_id:"5751e2b315cdbc58164df7cd"},function(err,data)  
{

    if(err)
    {
        console.log("couldnot load the group forum");

    }
    else
    {
        console.log("forum notificationids are"+data);

       //the below query returns result as empty  
        NotificationModel.find({'_id':{$in:data}},function(err,result)
        {

        if(err)
        {
            console.log("couldnot load notifications "+err);

        }   
        else
        {
            console.log("notifications are sent to the clientand result is"+result);


        } 

        });



    }
```

the output of the above code when run is :

*forum notification ids are
{ notificationids: [ 5751e2be15cdbc58164df7d0,
                    5751e2c415cdbc58164df7d1 ],
  __v: 0,
  _id: 5751e2b315cdbc58164df7cd 
}
notifications are sent to the client and result is*

As you can clearly see result is empty. i duno where i am doing wrong. i tried casting notificationids array elements to ObjectIds using

```
notificationids.map(function(o){return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(o);});
```

But this,as expected gave an error :

mongoose.Types.ObjectId error "Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters");

I also tried storing the objectids as strings but that dint work too.

thanks in advance.

Comment: So you know your data returned from ForumModel.find look like this `{ notificationids: [ 5751e2be15cdbc58164df7d0, 5751e2c415cdbc58164df7d1 ], __v: 0, _id: 5751e2b315cdbc58164df7cd }` so it's object, but you still use it as an array `NotificationModel.find({'_id':{$in:data}}` WHY? and since $in operator expects array not an object you get no results so simply use `data.notificationids` like this `NotificationModel.find({'_id':{$in:data.notificationids}}`

Comment: ya..figured it out after some code walkthrough..thanks.  :P

Comment: Why you can not use mongoose populate .  Refer this link http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html